# Request to google directions api wrongly asks for sensor

Tags: python, json, google-maps, urllib2, urllib

I am requesting directions from Google in Python, and I get the following response in JSON:

```
{
error_message: "The 'sensor' parameter specified in the request must be set to either 'true' or 'false'.",
routes: [ ],
status: "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

The url I hit is http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json and the data I send is below:

```
data = {
    'origin': origin,
    'destination': destination,
    'mode': mode,
    'sensor': 'false',
    'departure_time': departure_time
}
```

Note the sensor attribute. The respective attributes are London, Karachi, None, 'false' and None.
The way I send the request is:

```
req = urllib2.Request(google.urls['directions'], urllib.urlencode(data))
r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
return HttpResponse(r, content_type="application/json")
```

Does anyone know why this doenst work? All the searches around this problem lead me to people missing it out of their script tags.

Comment: Have you tried changing `'false'` to `False` (no quotes)?

Comment: You're sending a string not a boolean I'm going to guess, as mentioned above, if that doesn't work try appending the sensor section to the url.

Comment: I have tried this yes. The same result happens

Comment: You are sending a POST, not a GET request, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the parameters in the *URL*; the second argument to `urllib2.Request()` is for *POST* data instead, but you want a `GET` request here:

```
req = urllib2.Request('{}?{}'.format(google.urls['directions'], urllib.urlencode(data)))
```

Comment: Yeah this is correct, forgive my answer, I don't know python and presumed you were doing this. The url you need (given your parameters) is: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=london&destination=karachi&sensor=false which you will have to build as shown above.

Comment: @Swires: The parameters are being built correctly, just not included in the right location.

Comment: This was correct, thanks very much. although I dont understand the '{}?{}'.format part. What does it do?

Comment: That's just string formatting; `{}` is a placeholder, and Python fills in those slots with the arguments to the `.format()` method. The result is that you get url, followed by a question mark, followed by the GET parameters.